# What are some common ways for songwriters and lyricists to find each other online?

Tags: composition, songwriting, lyrics

Let's say I'm pretty comfortable at composing but bad at writing lyrics (or vice versa). What are the best ways for me to connect with a proficient lyricist online? Are there any "songwriter expertise exchange", collaboration-focused web sites for people to find each other if they're looking to set up a songwriting team?

Comment: American Songwriter, musicians in you neighborhood on FB, Reverbnation

Comment: This is actually a very good question. I find Facebook though, for things like this can be hit and miss. Maybe too much so?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into Facebook groups relating to this field. You can definitely find some kind of collaboration group out there. If this falls short, try out LinkedIn, it's a great resource for networking and finding new opportunities.